# Looking for Iterative Resolver

Tags: internal-dns, domain-name-system

I am looking for an Iterative Resolver server - a server that would handle the DNS resolutions for PC users in an environment. I am well aware of the Microsoft DNS and Bind, and also of free services like Google DNS and OpenDNS.

However, I am looking for alternative solution which I can install on premise. Any suggestions recommendations? (paid - free - or open source)

Comment: Looking for a bit of insight: What's wrong with MS DNS or BIND? They both fulfill the requirements of your question.

Comment: MS DNS won't do DNSSEC validation, if that matters.

Comment: Is not about what is wrong with MS or Bind. They all have pros and cons. I did not want to be stuck with selecting between the two, I wanted to test alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I usually install a linux box with unbound to act as a resolver for the network. It's simple enough to configure on Debian: just install the system, then unbound and make it listen on the LAN interface instead of 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Both Bind and Microsoft's implementation can be - and usually are - installed on premise. Bind is also free, and requires a U*X like operating system, usually linux, though I think I remember a windoze implementation existed. MS's' comes with any "server" OS (not free). (If you chose the linux path, you will also find there's a smattering of "lite" resolvers you could use instead of bind.)

So before we probe any further, could you clarify why MS/Bind do not satisfy you?

Cheers

Comment: BIND does exist for Windows, as does Unbound.

Comment: I simply wanted to test and compare different solutions. Did not want to be stuck to those default 2 DNS resolver solutions.

Comment: If so, then dnsmasq (linux) may be for you. It also bundles a dhcp server (which I believe can be turned off). There is also something called (I think) djbdns, which I cannot stand in the least - but then, I cannot stand qmail, either (same author/philosophy). If you like qmail, you may want to look into that. As far as "stuck" goes, BIND was - and still is, AFAIK -  the reference implementation for nameservers. Please also note that, in AD - or even windows domain - situations, turning off nameserving in the DC is a real PITA.